# tmux no longer lists each session in a group (C-b s)

Tags: tmux

With "*old*" `tmux`, each session in a group was listed separately when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> (or `choose-tree -s`)... (certainly `2.1` and `2.6`, I don't know how recently this persists)

For example, note how both `test` and `test2` are on separate lines, but both are noted as `group 0`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.04 bash
root@be06ee1f6f86:/#
root@be06ee1f6f86:/# apt update && apt install -y tmux
[...]
root@be06ee1f6f86:/# tmux -V
tmux 2.1
root@be06ee1f6f86:/# tmux new -As test
<--- inside tmux --->
root@be06ee1f6f86:/# tmux detach
<--- outside tmux --->
[detached (from session test)]
root@be06ee1f6f86:/# tmux new -As test2 -t test
<--- inside tmux --->
root@be06ee1f6f86:/# tmux choose-tree -s
<--- choose-tree --->
(0) + test: 1 windows (group 0)
(1) + test2: 1 windows (group 0) (attached)
```

On more recent versions, things behave differently, and A) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> no longer works to escape the tree (<kbd>q</kbd> must be used), but also B) the two sessions are listed on one line, making it impossible to pick "*the other one*" (certainly `3.0a` and `3.2a` are affected):

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:22.04 bash
root@94da749ff5aa:/# apt update && apt install -y tmux
root@94da749ff5aa:/# tmux -V
tmux 3.2a
root@94da749ff5aa:/# tmux new -As test
<--- inside tmux --->
root@94da749ff5aa:/# tmux detach
<--- outside tmux --->
[detached (from session test)]
root@94da749ff5aa:/# tmux new -As test2 -t test
<--- inside tmux --->
root@94da749ff5aa:/# tmux choose-tree -s
<--- choose-tree --->
(0) + test2: 1 windows (group test: test,test2) (attached)
```

Is this a fundamental change in `tmux`, or is there a config option to revert these changes? Ideally both re-enabling `^C` (though that's muscle memory that will adjust), and in particular display each session on a separate line? (I've had a rummage with no luck)

I know I can view them with `^B:ls`, and pick the correct session with `^B:new -As ${name}`, but I don't want to type all that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, having written out that question, I went digging in a new place... [`tmux/CHANGES`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/b777780/CHANGES#L1054-L1055)

> Only show first member of session groups in tree mode (-G flag to choose-tree to show all).

Sure enough, `choose-tree -sG` does the bulk of what I'm after (ignoring `^C`).

Put this into effect by adding the following to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -T prefix s choose-tree -ZGs
```

... it's in the man page too, doh.

> `-G` includes all sessions in any session groups in the tree rather than only the first.